# History of Path algebras

Tags: mathematics, terminology, abstract-algebra

I want some references that point the inventor of Path algebras and history/evolution of these algebras from the first idea. If possible.

I tried to search in many different places, but all times, the route stops at Gabriel.

Thanks.

PS: I asked this question in [math.stackexchange.com](http://%20%20I%20want%20some%20references%20that%20point%20the%20inventor%20of%20Path%20algebras%20and%20history/evolution%20of%20these%20algebras%20from%20the%20first%20idea.%20If%20possible.%20%20I%20tried%20to%20search%20in%20many%20different%20places,%20but%20all%20times,%20the%20route%20stops%20at%20Gabriel.%20%20Thanks.) and they suggested me to ask it here.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that it did not start with Gabriel? Neither Google Scholar nor MathSciNet return any hits on "path algebra" before 1972.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. how is the real inventor? or path algebras have before another name? They also called quiver algebras.

Comment: "Quiver" is an even later term, and they did not become prominent until applications in string theory. What makes you think that Gabriel was not the originator? His paper only has three references, and none of them looks like his source.